# sum and interval of convergence of geometric series

Tags: calculus

> Find the sum of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\bigg(x^{2n}+3^{n}\cdot x^{2n+1}\bigg)$$ and also find interval of convergence of that series

What i try $$S=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^{2n}+x+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}3^{n}\cdot x^{2n+1}$$

$$S=\frac{1}{1-x^2}+x+\frac{3x^3}{1-3x^2}$$

Interval of convergence is $$x^2<1\;\; \text{and} \;\;3x^2<1$$

So overall interval of convergence is $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<x<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Longrightarrow x\in\bigg(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)$$

Is my sum is right and also please tell me my interval of convergence is right.

If not then please tell me how can i find right sum and right interval of convergence. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is${}{}$.

Answer (score 3):

For the sum we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} + x\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(3x^2)^n}$=$\frac{1}{1-x^2} +\frac{x}{1-3x^2}$ where we have used the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^{n} = \frac{a}{1-r}$ when valid.

Your interval of convergence is correct. Alternatively we can write $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.